# React How creating a hook with a function with a parameter passed as a prop that dose not reference the parameter at hooks creation

Tags: reactjs

I have a hook called DragAndSize and I have my app.

the the app looks like

```
function App(){

    const [toolTips, set_toolTips] = useState([]);

    console.log(`------------------------- reload -------------------------`);
    return(
        <div>
            <button
                onClick={()=>{
                    let temp_toolTips = [... toolTips];
                    temp_toolTips.push(
                        <DragAndSize
                            dragAndSize={{
                                left: 20,
                                top: 20,
                                width : 400,
                                height : 400,
                                hidden : false,
                                zIndex : 1000
                            }}
                            styleParent={{
                                backgroundColor: "blue",
                                borderRadius: "10px",
                                borderColor : "balck",
                                borderWidth : "thick",
                            }}
                            closeFunction={()=>{
                                console.log(toolTips)
                            }}
                        >
                        </DragAndSize>
                    )
                    set_toolTips(temp_toolTips);
                }}
            >
                add
            </button>

            {toolTips.map((i, index)=>{return(
                <div key={index}>
                    {i}
                </div>
            )})}
        </div>
    )
}
```

the DragAndSize

```
function DragAndSize(props){

    /*------------------------- util -------------------------*/
    let get_highest_index = ()=>{
        let elements = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
        let highest_index = 0;

        for(let i = 0; i < elements.length -1; i++){
            if(Boolean(parseInt(elements[i].style.zIndex))){
                if(parseInt(elements[i].style.zIndex) > highest_index){
                    highest_index = parseInt(elements[i].style.zIndex);
                }
            }
        }
        return(highest_index + 1)
    }

    /*------------------------- mouse -------------------------*/
    const [trackMouse, set_trackMouse] = useState(false);
    const [mouseDown, set_mouseDown] = useState({x: 0, y: 0});
    const [mouseUp, set_mouseUp] = useState({x: 0, y: 0});

    /*-------------------- ToolTip --------------------*/
    let dragAndSize = props.dragAndSize ?? {
        left: 100,
        top: 100,
        width : 200,
        height : 200,
        hidden : false,
        zIndex : 100
    }
    const [trackToolTipMove, set_trackToolTipMove] = useState(false);
    const [trackToolTipSize, set_trackToolTipSize] = useState(false);
    const [dragAndSizeStart, set_dragAndSizeStart] = useState(dragAndSize);
    const [dragAndSizeEnd, set_dragAndSizeEnd] = useState(dragAndSize);

    let userIsDragingOrDroping = ()=>{ 
        if(!trackToolTipMove && !trackToolTipSize){
            return(0)
        }else{
            return(100)
        }
    }

    /*------------------------- props/content -------------------------*/
    let move = props.move ?? `❖`;
    let size = props.size ?? ``
    let close = props.close ?? `❌`;
    
    let defaultStyleParent = {
        overflow : "hidden",
        zIndex : `${dragAndSizeEnd.zIndex}`,
        position: "absolute",
        left: `${dragAndSizeEnd.left}px`,
        top: `${dragAndSizeEnd.top}px`,
        width : `${dragAndSizeEnd.width}px`,
        height : `${dragAndSizeEnd.height}px`,
        display: "grid",
        gridTemplateRows: "auto 1fr auto",

    }
    let defaultStyleChild = {}
    let styleParent = {...props.styleParent, ... defaultStyleParent};
    let styleChild = {...props.styleChild, ... defaultStyleChild};
    let defaultCloseFunction = ()=>{console.log(`you got to do this part your self`)};
    // let closeFunction = props.closeFunction ?? defaultCloseFunction;


    if(dragAndSizeEnd.hidden == true){
        return(null);
    }else{

        return(
            <div
                onClick={()=>{
                    let temp_get_highest_index = get_highest_index();
                    let temp_dragAndSizeStart = {... dragAndSizeStart};
                    let temp_dragAndSizeEnd = {... dragAndSizeEnd};
                    temp_dragAndSizeStart.zIndex = temp_get_highest_index;
                    temp_dragAndSizeEnd.zIndex = temp_get_highest_index;
                }}
                style={{
                    zIndex : `${dragAndSizeEnd.zIndex}`,
                    position: "absolute",
                    left: "0px",
                    top: "0px",
                    width : `${userIsDragingOrDroping()}vw`,
                    height : `${userIsDragingOrDroping()}vh`,
                }}

                onMouseMove={(event)=>{
                    if(userIsDragingOrDroping()){
                        set_mouseUp({
                            x : event.clientX,
                            y : event.clientY,
                        })

                        // ToolTip
                        if(trackToolTipMove){
                            set_dragAndSizeEnd({
                                left: dragAndSizeStart.left + (mouseUp.x - mouseDown.x),
                                top: dragAndSizeStart.top + (mouseUp.y - mouseDown.y),
                                width : dragAndSizeStart.width,
                                height : dragAndSizeStart.height,
                            })
                        }
                        if(trackToolTipSize){
                            set_dragAndSizeEnd({
                                left: dragAndSizeStart.left,
                                top: dragAndSizeStart.top,
                                width : dragAndSizeStart.width + (mouseUp.x - mouseDown.x),
                                height : dragAndSizeStart.height + (mouseUp.y - mouseDown.y),
                            })
                        }
                    }
                }}
                onMouseUp={()=>{
                    set_trackMouse(false);

                    // ToolTip
                    set_trackToolTipMove(false)
                    set_trackToolTipSize(false)
                    set_dragAndSizeStart(dragAndSizeEnd);
                }}
            >
                <div
                    onClick={()=>{
                
                        let temp_get_highest_index = get_highest_index();
                        let temp_dragAndSizeStart = {... dragAndSizeStart};
                        let temp_dragAndSizeEnd = {... dragAndSizeEnd};
                        temp_dragAndSizeStart.zIndex = temp_get_highest_index;
                        temp_dragAndSizeEnd.zIndex = temp_get_highest_index;

                        set_dragAndSizeStart(temp_dragAndSizeStart);
                        set_dragAndSizeEnd(temp_dragAndSizeEnd);
                    }}
                    style={styleParent}
                >
                    <div
                        style={{
                            display: "grid",
                            gridTemplateColumns: "auto auto",
                        }}
                    >
                        <div
                            onMouseDown={(event)=>{

                                dragAndSizeStart.zIndex = get_highest_index();
                                set_dragAndSizeStart(dragAndSizeStart);
                                dragAndSizeEnd.zIndex = get_highest_index();
                                set_dragAndSizeEnd(dragAndSizeStart);

                                set_trackToolTipMove(true);
                                set_mouseDown({
                                    x : event.clientX,
                                    y : event.clientY,
                                })
                                set_mouseUp({
                                    x : event.clientX,
                                    y : event.clientY,
                                })
                            }}
                        >
                            {move}
                        </div>
                        <div
                            onMouseDown={(event)=>{
                                // THIS IS WHERE YOU CLOSE THING
                                
                                if(props.closeFunction == undefined){
                                    defaultCloseFunction()
                                }else{
                                    props.closeFunction();
                                }

                            }}
                            style={{
                                textAlign : "right"
                            }}
                        >
                            {close}
                        </div>
                    </div>

                        <div
                            style={styleChild}
                        >
                            {props.children}
                        </div>
                    <div
                        onMouseDown={(event)=>{

                            let temp_get_highest_index = get_highest_index();
                            let temp_dragAndSizeStart = {... dragAndSizeStart};
                            let temp_dragAndSizeEnd = {... dragAndSizeEnd};
                            temp_dragAndSizeStart.zIndex = temp_get_highest_index;
                            temp_dragAndSizeEnd.zIndex = temp_get_highest_index;

                            set_trackToolTipSize(true);
                            set_mouseDown({
                                x : event.clientX,
                                y : event.clientY,
                            })
                            set_mouseUp({
                                x : event.clientX,
                                y : event.clientY,
                            })
                        }}
                        style={{
                            textAlign: "right",
                        }}
                    >
                        {size}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

when I am setting the closeFunction for DragAndSize I am getting an outdated copy. on the first div Im getting an empty array the second div gives me an array with one element in it. dose any one know who I can get the up to date parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Quick fix (but probably bad solution):

Use a [`Ref`](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html):

```
const [toolTips, set_toolTips] = useState([]);
const toolipsRef = useRef(toolTips);

useEffect(() => {
  toolTips.current = toolTips;
}, [toolTips]);

...

closeFunction={ () => {
  console.log(toolipsRef.current)
} }
```

Also, note that your new state is based on the previous one, so you should be using [functional updates](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates), as shown in the example below.

Better alternative:

- Instead of adding the rendered component to state, only add the props for the tooltips you want to render that do not change (`closeFunction` won't be in the state).

  If needed, you can add a `tooltipType` prop, which in this case will be `"DragAndSize"`, but could be something different if you have other types of "tooltip" components

  ```
  <button
    onClick={() => {
      set_toolTips((...prevTooltips) => ([
        ...prevTooltips,
        {
          tooltipType: "DragAndSize"
          dragAndSize: {
            left: 20,
            top: 20,
            width : 400,
            height : 400,
            hidden : false,
            zIndex : 1000
          }
          styleParent: {
            backgroundColor: "blue",
            borderRadius: "10px",
            borderColor : "balck",
            borderWidth : "thick",
          },
        },
      ]);
    }>
    Add
  </button>
  ```
- You then render these as you would normally do using `toolTips.map(...)` and adding the missing props (`closeFunction` in this case):

  ```
  toolTips.map(({ tooltipType, ...tooltipProps }, index) => {
    let tooltipElement = null;

    if (tooltipType === "DragAndSize") {
      tooltipElement = (
        <DragAndSize
          { ...tooltipProps }
          closeFunction={ () => console.log(toolTips) }/>
      );
    }

    return tooltipElement ? (
      <div key={index}>
        { tooltipElement }
      </div>
    ) : null;
  });
  ```

Comment: Ya see I thought of the same thing earlier you would think that that would solve it but it doesn't. when you create the hook it gets a copy of your peram  and all the reff dose is create an extra copy.

Comment: @SassanKermani Did you add the `useEffect` to update the ref as the state changes? Also, see my updated answer, you should also be using functional updates when you update the state.

Comment: thats like acutely a really good answer thank you. So basically just save all the params in the app as in my state without the actual hook and then recreate all the DragAndSize on reload that way the data they are referencing is current.